# how to convert static urls from dynamic urls?

Tags: url, dynamic, static

Can you please help me this?
i have classified site: 99clix.in/latest/ , Actually it is under construction. it creates dynamic dynamics urls, i want to convert into seo friendly urls.

**Eg:**

**DYnamic Url:** http://www.99clix.in/latest/index.php?welcome/category/Mobile-Phones/Mobile-phones

**Static Url:** 
 http://www.99clix.in/latest/Mobile-Phones/Mobile-phones.

Same way i need to create for all categories and subcategory  as per user search.

can you help me out for this?

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in .htaccess file in your root directory, this will allow you allow you to access url  without index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Please provide little more detail about your application so we  can provide more personalized solution -- are you using any framework etc..

Comment: Thank you Arun, this is done by codeignator framework.